# My control is "not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'"

Tags: c#, custom-controls, user-controls, extend

So I have another noodle-scratcher (for me anyway).

I'm trying to create my own custom control in a CMS I only have partial source code for (i.e. samples the vendor has supplied to me). Basically I have created a class called `DataDefinitionContent` which extends `ControlBase`. Now, from what I can garner from the metadata, `ControlBase` extends `UserControl`, so I would have thought this would run without a drama. Can anyone shed any light on why this might not be working for me?

---

My Class:

```
public partial class DataDefinitionContent : ControlBase, ICustomControl<DataDefinition>
{
... Stuff
}
```

ControlBase:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace CMS.Web
{
    public class ControlBase : UserControl
    {
    ... Stuff
    }
}
```

My ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataDefinitionContent.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="CMS.Admin.WebUI.CustomControls.DataDefinitionContent, CoA.Admin.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" %>
```

The error I'm getting:

> Parser Error Message:
> 'CMS.Admin.WebUI.CustomControls.DataDefinitionContent,
> CoA.Admin.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> is not allowed here because it does
> not extend class
> 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.
>
> Line 1:
> <%@ Control Language="C#"
> AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataDefinitionContent.ascx.cs"

Comment: Is your partial class inside a namespace?

Comment: Actually, no it isn't. Can you give me a clue as to how I would go about deciphering which namespace I should put it in? (OP is still a newbie)

Comment: well you have ="CMS.Admin.WebUI.CustomControls.DataDefinitionContent, CoA.Admin.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" in your Inherits which I don't think you need.  The namespace looks like CMS.Admin.WebUI.CustomControls,  though controlbase looks like its in CMS.Web

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try putting your partial class in

```
namespace CMS.Web
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but I ended up approaching the problem from a different angle. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool man.  What approach did you take?  The whole namespace issue can become an utter nightmare if you ever convert a WebSite to Web Application.

Comment: More specifically the 'designer' file doesn't always generate with the proper namespace. Updating it to have the right namespace fixes the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error when the name of the class that was extending the UserControl class was not the name used in ASP inclusion. I made the change to the class name and redeployed the solution. The problem was fixed.

Comment: When rename the file, the name of the class is not update on every sites, this is my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was thrown, because of missing namespace.

Comment: More specifically the 'designer' file doesn't always generate with the proper namespace. Updating it to have the right namespace fixes the issue.