# Parse Error When Going To Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, parse-error

I am getting a parse error when I go to my web application. I am not sure how to solve this, as I am new to WebApps. I have read some things about adding it into the right namespace, is that what I need to do? How would I do that?

You can see the error below or go to the page itself: [hyperslurp.com/ccrm/](http://hyperslurp.com/ccrm/)

[image: The Error I Am Getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, it seems that your codebehind page doesn't derive from `System.Web.UI.Page`. So make sure that this is the case with the `Default.aspx.cs` file:

```
namespace CompostCrew
{
    public partial class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually already had this, but the problem was I had deleted the _ in front of Default by mistake, added it back in and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other answers that might help you.  Check out:

[Parser Error: '_Default' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page' & MasterType declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057817/parser-error-default-is-not-allowed-here-because-it-does-not-extend-class-s)

[My control is "not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665521/my-control-is-not-allowed-here-because-it-does-not-extend-class-system-web-ui)